# how to compare two date using asp:CompareValidator which is in the format of dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I'm trying to compare two dates which is in the format of **dd-mm-yyyy** 
i used the code below

```
 <input  type="text" id="ocd" size="25" title="Closure Date" placeholder="Possible Closure Date " runat="server">   // where this exists in dd-mm-yyyy format 
 <input  type="text" id="od" size="25" title="Closure Date" placeholder=" Date Of Opportunity" runat="server">    // where this exists in dd-mm-yyyy format 
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ValidationGroup = "Date" ForeColor = "Red" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate = "od" ControlToCompare = "ocd" Operator = "LessThanEqual" Type = "Date"
            ErrorMessage="Receipt date must be less than Closure date."></asp:CompareValidator>
```

but its comparing only **dd** in **dd-mm-yyyy** how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CompareValidator to validate two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169609/comparevalidator-to-validate-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried this method now this works fine for **dd-mm-yyyy** format

in web.config file

```
<system.web>
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" /></system.web>
```

upon updating this in .aspx page

add **Culture = "en-GB"**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="filename.aspx.cs" Inherits="<%--your backend code--%>"   Culture = "en-GB"  %>
```

now add CompareValidator to the comparing dates

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ValidationGroup = "Date" ForeColor = "Red" runat="server" ControlToValidate = "startdate" ControlToCompare = "enddate" Operator = "LessThan" Type = "Date" ErrorMessage="Start date must be less than End date."></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Start Date: <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Text = "24/02/1999"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
    End Date: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Text = "31/12/1988"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ValidationGroup = "Date" ForeColor = "Red" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate = "txtStartDate" ControlToCompare = "txtEndDate" Operator = "LessThan" Type = "Date"
    ErrorMessage="Start date must be less than End date."></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Below article can help you in detail :-

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Compare-dates-in-ddmmyyyy-format-using-ASPNet-CompareValidator.aspx

**Edit 1:-**

I think you need to use custom validator here, like showing in below link :-

[ASP.NET validator to compare two date difference is not more than 12 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309912/asp-net-validator-to-compare-two-date-difference-is-not-more-than-12-months)

You need to build your logic here for date comparison, link is just for reference.

**Edit 2:-**

```
protected void ValidateDuration(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime firstDate= DateTime.Parse(txbStartDate.Text);
    DateTime secondDate = DateTime.Parse(txbEndDate.Text);

    if(firstDate <= secondDate)
    {
      e.IsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
      e.IsValid = true;
    }          
}
```

**Edit 3:-**

If above part is not working than you need to change page Culture property for date :-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="_Default" 
    Culture = "ar-MA" %>
```

For full list of Culture, please check below link :-

http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx

Comment: i have already tried this my problem is with date format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: its actually comparing only **dd**  in dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: oh sorry missed that part, let me update the answer.

Comment: please check updated answer, please update Edit 2 according to your need.

Comment: i appreciate your help but its not working it directly accepts all the value and submits the from

Comment: `protected void validateDate_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {

            DateTime firstDate = DateTime.Parse(od.Value);
            DateTime secondDate = DateTime.Parse(ocd.Value);

            if (firstDate == secondDate)
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }          
        }`

Comment: `<asp:CustomValidator ID="validateDate"  OnServerValidate="validateDate_ServerValidate"
             ErrorMessage="Dates are too far apart" runat="server" />`  the asp part is over here

Comment: Please see Edit 3 and let me know if it works for you.